# RESTful deployment error

Tags: apache, rest, apache-wink

I am trying to deploy RESTful webservice on Apache Tomcat build using Apache Wink in ECLIPSE IDE. I am getting below error while trying to run my app on server:

```
Feb 02, 2013 8:47:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\php\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\sw\Java\apache-maven-2.2.1-bin\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin;D:\PR\apache-ant-1.8.4-bin\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin;C:\cTAKES-2.5.0;C:\cTAKES-2.5.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;C:\Downloads\Apache-Subversion-1.7.6\bin;UIMA_HOME\bin;D:\sw\Apache AXIS and JavaBeans Activation framework\axis-src-1_4\axis-1_4\lib\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;C:\Program Files\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit\;D:\sw\eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32\eclipse;;.
Feb 02, 2013 8:47:04 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Books' did not find a matching property.
Feb 02, 2013 8:47:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 02, 2013 8:47:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 02, 2013 8:47:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 804 ms
Feb 02, 2013 8:47:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 02, 2013 8:47:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.22
Feb 02, 2013 8:47:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 02, 2013 8:47:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 02, 2013 8:47:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 458 ms
148 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO org.apache.wink.common.internal.application.ApplicationFileLoader - Loading application from META-INF/core/wink-providers.
471 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet - Using application class com.ibm.devworks.ws.rest.books.BookWebApp named in init-param javax.ws.rs.Application
472 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet - com.ibm.devworks.ws.rest.books.BookWebApp
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.devworks.ws.rest.books.BookWebApp
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.getApplication(RestServlet.java:163)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.createRequestProcessor(RestServlet.java:113)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.init(RestServlet.java:87)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:836)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Feb 02, 2013 8:47:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet restSdkService as unavailable
Feb 02, 2013 8:47:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet restSdkService
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.ibm.devworks.ws.rest.books.BookWebApp
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.init(RestServlet.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:836)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Where am I missing??

Thanks.

Regards,
Piyush

Comment: it seems that tomcat server failed to find the class : com.ibm.devworks.ws.rest.books.BookWebApp. Did you include such dependency/jar in the classpath and deploy it along with your app to tomcat?

Comment: I was missing .class files for my application. Thanks.